# Why, I can't update my react app hosted on Digital Ocean?

Tags: nginx, service, digital-ocean, sudo

I hosted my website on Digital Ocean and I installed Nginx to serve it, 
when I tried to update my react app it did not work 
I tried to restart Nginx with :

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

It did not work it is still the old version that is served 
so I removed the cache of Nginx with

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/nginx/
```

Then I restarted but it is still the old version 
so I tried to stop Nginx

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Then

```
sudo service nginx  status
```

To see if it worked, and even if the status of Nginx is not active the web site is still working and the old version of the website is still here 
I tried several think like

```
sudo nginx -s stop
sudo nginx -s quit
```

same think , the old version is still here 
even when I shut off the digital ocean droplet(VM) the link to the website still work with the old version even if when I ping to it I don't have a response

please help me understand what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to clean the cache from your local browser?

If you do not want to clean local browser cache, open a new browser in incognito mode.

For debugging without risk of cache local, i would recommend open a browser in developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd>), change to tab network and click button `disable cache`.

[image]

The `disable cache` option is only active if developer console is open.

Comment: i feel stupid i spend 2 day trying to debug this  I never thought it could be a problem of browser cash  